# Join 2 Query's with The same information only different search criteria

Tags: sql, db2

I have a Query that I either want to join with another one with the same information only 1 of the Criteria is different, Or I want to use the 1 Query to pull the top 10 results for each of the 4 values in 1 column. You can see I have 1 line Commented out, If you un-comment that and comment out the line below that is the other Select Statement I need. I understand I am not explaining this the best but If you understand and are willing to help I would appreciate it.

```
SELECT coalesce(C.CUSTOMER_GROUP, C.CLIENT_ID) "Customer Group",
max(c.name) "Name",
round(sum(CHARGES),2) "Freight Charges",
round(sum(XCHARGES),2) "Accessorials",
round(sum(TOTAL_CHARGES),2) "Total Charges",
max(c.user7) as OR_Data,
max(cd.data) as test


FROM  TLORDER T, client C, custom_data as cd
where (src_table_key = t.customer
and custdef_id = '5')
and t.bill_to_code = c.CLIENT_ID
  and t.pick_up_by between '2015-1-1' and current date
  and T.SITE_ID = 'SITE5'
  AND (t.INTERFACE_STATUS_F IS NULL  OR t.INTERFACE_STATUS_F>-1)

--and (select cu.data from custom_data as cu where custdef_id = '5' and src_table_key = t.customer) in ('DIRECT', 'BROKER')
and (select cu.data from custom_data as cu where custdef_id = '5' and src_table_key = t.customer) in ('AGENT', 'INTERLINE')

and current_Status not in ('CANCL','QUOTE')


group by coalesce(C.CUSTOMER_GROUP, C.CLIENT_ID)
order by 5 desc
fetch first 10 rows only
with ur
```

Comment: Ummmm...  [Union](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better way, but...

```
SELECT coalesce(C.CUSTOMER_GROUP, C.CLIENT_ID) "Customer Group",
max(c.name) "Name",
round(sum(CHARGES),2) "Freight Charges",
round(sum(XCHARGES),2) "Accessorials",
round(sum(TOTAL_CHARGES),2) "Total Charges",
max(c.user7) as OR_Data,
max(cd.data) as test


FROM  TLORDER T, client C, custom_data as cd
where (src_table_key = t.customer
and custdef_id = '5')
and t.bill_to_code = c.CLIENT_ID
  and t.pick_up_by between '2015-1-1' and current date
  and T.SITE_ID = 'SITE5'
  AND (t.INTERFACE_STATUS_F IS NULL  OR t.INTERFACE_STATUS_F>-1)

and (select cu.data from custom_data as cu where custdef_id = '5' and src_table_key = t.customer) in ('DIRECT', 'BROKER')
--and (select cu.data from custom_data as cu where custdef_id = '5' and src_table_key = t.customer) in ('AGENT', 'INTERLINE')

and current_Status not in ('CANCL','QUOTE')


group by coalesce(C.CUSTOMER_GROUP, C.CLIENT_ID)
order by 5 desc
fetch first 10 rows only
with ur

-- Using "UNION" will essentially append the 2nd query to the end of the first
UNION

SELECT coalesce(C.CUSTOMER_GROUP, C.CLIENT_ID) "Customer Group",
max(c.name) "Name",
round(sum(CHARGES),2) "Freight Charges",
round(sum(XCHARGES),2) "Accessorials",
round(sum(TOTAL_CHARGES),2) "Total Charges",
max(c.user7) as OR_Data,
max(cd.data) as test


FROM  TLORDER T, client C, custom_data as cd
where (src_table_key = t.customer
and custdef_id = '5')
and t.bill_to_code = c.CLIENT_ID
  and t.pick_up_by between '2015-1-1' and current date
  and T.SITE_ID = 'SITE5'
  AND (t.INTERFACE_STATUS_F IS NULL  OR t.INTERFACE_STATUS_F>-1)

--and (select cu.data from custom_data as cu where custdef_id = '5' and src_table_key = t.customer) in ('DIRECT', 'BROKER')
and (select cu.data from custom_data as cu where custdef_id = '5' and src_table_key = t.customer) in ('AGENT', 'INTERLINE')

and current_Status not in ('CANCL','QUOTE')


group by coalesce(C.CUSTOMER_GROUP, C.CLIENT_ID)
order by 5 desc
fetch first 10 rows only
with ur
```